# Kentico system tables form validation

Tags: kentico

kentico 6
i'm using custom registration webpart and would like my  form validation to work like this->

on validation show:
1. a red star next to each input that is invalid
2. have a validation summary at top form.

Kentico allows only one validation message per feidl so I'm not sure how to solve this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either customize the form validation or you can wait for the 7.0 version ;) The 7.0 version supports such a  behavior by default (with a nice error summary and links/anchors to the fields with incorrect input). So if it's a possibility to use Kentico 7.0RC or to wait to the final version, I would recommend that approach, since your customization in 6.0 would be obsolete.

If you want to achieve this in 6.0, please check this example on validation messages in Kentico bizforms:

In the examples is viewBiz the codename of the BizForm we are working with. It is recommended to create a clone of the web part before doing any changes ([documentation on changing code of standard web parts](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?modifying_the_code_of_standard_web_parts.htm)), and the changes are done on those cloned code files.

```
protected void viewBiz_OnValidationFailed()
{

    ((CMS.ExtendedControls.LocalizedLabel)this.viewBiz.BasicForm.FieldErrorLabels["FirstName"]).Text="Field specific error message";

}
```

As you can see you need to get the error label as a control from the hash table and set it's properties properly (here text).
To set the main validation message you can simply use the code below:

this.viewBiz.ValidationErrorMessage = "Main error message";

To access the field values for validation please check the code below (the field is called "FirstName" in the example):

```
protected void viewBiz_OnAfterValidate()
{
        this.viewBiz.ValidationErrorMessage = "Main error message";
        string find = "FirstName";
        Control cl = this.viewBiz.BasicForm.FindControl(find);

        string toValidate = "";

        if (cl != null)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)cl;
            toValidate = tb.Text.ToString().Trim();
        }
}
```

Please note, that you have to register all the mentioned methods in ihe bizform definition:

If you interrupt the processing of the BizForm you might have to save the data manually:

viewBiz.BasicForm.SaveData("redirect.to.this.url");

PS. We are monitoring our forums more often than stackoverflow ;)

Regards,
Boris Pocatko,
Kentico